# Which type of array should I use

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create an array with a list of players and which arena they are in. I don't know which type of array would be best suited.

It will hold information like this:

```
PlayerName : Arena
John : Arena1
Harry : Arena1
Dave : Arena2
Will : Arena2
```

You're help is much appreciated, I am new to Java and can't see this listed on the site, if it is please point me in that direction :)

Comment: There is only one kind of array: `YourClassOrPrimitiveType[] anArray`. If you mean which `Collection` to use, use `List` backed by `ArrayList` unless you have more requirements to hold the data.

Comment: Do you only need to store this data in pairs or you will also need to know which players are in an arena?

Answer (score 5):

That's a mapping from players to arenas.

I would create a `class Player` and a `class Arena`, so your data structure will be:

```
Map<Player, Arena> playerToArena = new HashMap<Player, Arena>();
```

I wouldn't use an array in this case, but, if you insist, you can write something similar to this:

```
class Pair { 
    Player player;
    Arena arena;
}

Pair[] array = new Pair[10];
// or
List<Pair> arrayList = new ArrayList<Pair>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved using a Map. E.g.,

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("name", "demo");
map.put("fname", "fdemo");
// etc
```

map.get("name"); // returns "demo"
Even more accurate to your example would be to declare:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
data.add(0, map);
data.get(0).get("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one type of array.  In an array, you put in an index, and you get out the corresponding item.  If you want to use an array to represent this information, I would make a class that contains where you can set the Player and the Arena values, and then store each object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a container class that contains a playername and arena name and create an array (or other collection of that)

```
private static final class ArenaPlayerContainer {
    private final String playerName;
    private final String arenaName;

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public String getArenaName() {
        return arenaName;
    }

    private ArenaPlayerContainer(String playerName, String arenaName) {

        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.arenaName = arenaName;
    }
}
```

then you can just create a `ArenaPlayerContainer[] arr = new ArenaPlayerContainer[10];`
for example

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get it, but I am assuming you want to user a hashmap or hashtable instead (use hashtable if you are using threads).

[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

This way you can extend PlayerName, Stack, Overflow, Word, Press with some custom class and use it with the map: `HashMap <CustomClass, Arena>`